# View moodle course content somewhere else

Tags: php, zend-framework, moodle, training-data

I have a special course (I know the id) , the artifacts of this course have to be displayed in some other part of my customized page.

I could do that by rendering the artifacts related to this course id from database tables like mdl_assignments, mdl_quiz etc.

But I want to know is there any inbuilt method to view the course content without any weekly/topic format.

I want just the artifact titles and the links to it

Note: I saw the code in course/view.php but it's little messed up.

I am using moodle 2.2

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there's a way. Enable webservices and use `core_course_get_contents`. Read this document to know how to do this: [Using web services - Moodle Wiki](http://docs.moodle.org/27/en/How_to_create_and_enable_a_web_service).

[image: The output of the web service]

Image above, output of the webservice ([credit](https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-28646)).

Moreover, you could take a look to the method used by the web service, `get_course_contents`. You can read its implementation here: https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/course/externallib.php#L61

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have already implemented it by fetching all type of assets directly from database.

Comment: Ok,good to hear that you solved your problem! Have a nice day:)